# How is state maintained within an application/web server?

Tags: jakarta-ee, stateful, stateful-session-bean

I understand what stateful and stateless session beans are and when to use them but I am curious as to how an application/web server knows that this object instance belongs to this client. Is a session id sent in the form of a cookie and the application/web server knows that this session object belongs to this particular client?

Comment: *"I understand what stateful and stateless session beans are and when to use them"* Sorry, this question alone is already evidence you clearly don't. The abovelinked duplicate explains the lifecycle of those beans and the duplicate here explains that of the HTTP session (which has **completely nothing** to do with the word "session" in "session beans"): http://stackoverflow.com/q/3106452

Comment: So what brought up this conversation is that I had a discussion with a colleague. My colleague suggests that every web application is stateless. I said i disagree with the statement, http is stateless but web applications can have state. For example a shopping cart, a shopping cart is maintained throughout each request. After this I said I wasn't a hundred percent sure how the server maintained state but other than a sessionId in the cookie. Either way my colleague still disagrees with me and just ended the conversation with, traditional web apps don't have state.....

Comment: I could find the definite answer, so I asked the question....thank you @BalusC

Answer (score -1):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_ID):

> The client usually stores and sends the token as an HTTP cookie and/or sends it as a parameter in GET or POST queries